# Berlin Tegel Airport to Halle (Saale)

Tags: trains, luggage, airport-transfer, txl

How can I travel from Berlin Tegel Airport to Halle (Saale) by train?

Is there any train access in the airport?

Also I have 30 kg of luggage with me.

Answer (score 10):

There is no train station at Tegel airport. You best shot is to take the [TXL Jet Express bus](http://www.berlin-airport.de/en/travellers-txl/to-and-from/buses-and-trains/local-public-transport/) to the central station (Hauptbahnhof).

There are plenty of train connections to Halle. Every two hours there is a non stop high speed train that does the trip in a little over an hour. However it's pricey: 47 Euro (unless you book a few weeks in advance). There are many other trains with connections which are as little as 20 Euro.

Cheapest would be a bus like [this](https://www.berlinlinienbus.de/search/#city_from_id=25&city_dest_id=63&date_fwrd=05.05.2016&hide_back=on&date_back=&adult=1&child=0&bicycle=0&fromStop=2000&toStop=6001&fromStopReturn=null&toStopReturn=null) which can be as little as 7 Euro. However, you need to check the departure point for the buses. This one leaves from Funkturm so you need to find the right bus from Tegel to get there.

Comment: It's worth noting that Google Maps knows all of Berlin's public transport times, so it's trivial to open the phone when you're in the Tegel WiFi and do a navigation search.